# Graphics bug after build in Unity 3d

Tags: unity

i made a terrain on unity. I haven't write scripts yet. But i am getting really big render difference between standalone version and editor verison. Please help me, have nice day.

In Editor:
[image: In Editor]

After build (standalone version):
[image: In Built]

Comment: What are the graphics settings on the standalone?

Comment: It looks like the light map isn't getting applied correctly. Can you confirm how you've set up your lights, scene render & lightmapping settings, in addition to the player graphics settings Sidar asked about?